# Liberal REGEX for Money

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a PHP application. I need to validate that a string is useable as a currency value. I would like the following to validate:

```
$5.00  
5  
5.00   
£5.00
```

I want the pattern to be liberal enough to accept a reasonable string. I would also like it to accept an currency symbol; however, to validate currency, it can be any character or characters because I'll ultimately store the value as a two decimal float. So, '$5.00' or 'USD 5.00' would become '5.00' when stored in the database. I'm currently using the following:

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/',$value)
```

It works for "5" or "5.00", but it does not account for the currency symbol. How do I adjust this to allow for the currency symbol?

Thank you!

EDIT: According to a comment below, it looks like my regex will allow too many decimals. Can you also help me sort out that issue?

Comment: I would imagine there is an existing *library* to do this. A single regular expression -- excluding a perl monstrosity ;) -- will likely not cover all the cases. The start is to determine *exactly which* cases are supported and what they mean, including conversion to an appropriate Money Type value.

Comment: @pst...thanks! I know this isn't an ideal use of regex, but I was just looking for a relatively simple way or providing some simple validation. This doesn't have to be bulletproof. Do you know of any such libraries?

Comment: You would need to have each individual case of currency denotators for this to work - $, euros, USD, etc. Otherwise, it will not be comprehensive enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow all currency symbols you will need to use [Unicode Character Properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

`\p{Sc}` or `\p{Currency_Symbol}`: any currency sign.

Try with this one:

```
$value=preg_replace('/^(\p{Sc}?\d*)((\.|,)\d\d\d)?\d*$/u','$1$2',$value);
```

But if you are expecting the number from an input, will be better make a [form](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-select-element) where the user specify the currency from a selectable list, and just take care whether the user will only introduce numbers, that's how PAYPAL does.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I was clear enough. I would need it to validate with any currency symbol, or if the user input something like 'USD'.

Comment: This will accept `5.1` and `5.111`, `.0` and `05`. It will not accept `5.` or currencies that use `,` as the fractional separator. There be dragons hiding in regular expressions.

Comment: @pst...thanks for pointing out that my regex will all allow `5.111`. I just added this to the question.

Comment: @nEAnnam: Don't forget to add the UTF-8 modifier, `/u`.  Unicode properties like `\p{Sc}` don't work without it.

Comment: @nEAnnam...thank you! I'm going to try this in a little bit. I do like the idea of having the user select the currency from a select; however, what I'm trying to do here is make sure that even if they enter something like "$5.00" and select the $ sign from the dropdown, I can validate the data. I ultimately strip out the $ sign for storage anyway.

Comment: @Sardine Your Welcome, but is not necessary allow the signs, since the people see the select box, they know the "implicity" currency, then is more easy for them to put a quantity.

Answer (score 1):

A regex monstrosity follows:

```
/^(?<currency_left>\p{Sc}|[A-Z]{3})?\s*
  (?<amount>(?:(?!,)[,\d]*)(?:(?=.\d)|(?<=\d))(?:\.\d*)?)\s*
  (?<currency_right>(?(currency_left)|(?:\p{Sc}|[A-Z]{3})))?$/ui
```

(\p{Sc} matches any currency symbol.)

This will match an optional 3-digit currency symbol or code, followed by a positive number, followed by a currency symbol or 3-digit code.  The number may include a decimal, or commas before the decimal.  The currency symbol can appear before or after the number, but not both.  The group Amount stores the decimal part, and currency_left and currency_right the currency part (currency_left and currency_right will not both match).